# How do I force Visual Studio 2019 to generate a .deploy file for an icon for ClickOnce deployment/install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm running into a problem publishing/installing a ClickOnce application being built in C# in Visual Studio 2019.  The application is being built using .NET Core 3.1 and WPF.

I have an icon I am using for the application that is included in the project with the filename "loader.ico".  The ClickOnce manifest is calling out for loader.ico, but the required *Loader.ico.deploy* file is not being generated when publishing, which is throwing an exception when trying to run the setup.exe to install the application to a client PC (actual filepaths have been replaced with [Path]:

```
+ Downloading file:///[Path]/x64/ClickOnce/Application Files/.NET Bootloader_1_0_0_4/loader.ico.deploy did not succeed.
    + Could not find file '[Path]\x64\ClickOnce\Application Files\.NET Bootloader_1_0_0_4\loader.ico.deploy'.
```

I have attempted a few things using what information on the problem I could find:

I set the Build Action for loader.ico to *Content* and set Copy to Output Directory to *Copy Always*.  I also set the "Settings>Application Files" setting for loader.ico to *Include*.  This has no effect on the resulting Publish, and no loader.ico.deploy file is generated.

I also receive the following in the output window when publishing:
***Unable to apply publish properties for item "loader.ico"***

I have also tried excluding loader.ico from the "Application Files", but this does not remove the reference in the .manifest file.

So now I am at a bit of a loss.  I don't know why it would demand a .deploy file for the icon (I'd think it would just be embedded?  No need for a separate icon file?).  I can't seem to get the ClickOnce publishing process to generate the required loader.ico.deploy file, and I can't seem to get the manifest to remove the reference to it.  What settings could be used to force the generation of this .deploy file (or force the manifest to not reference it)?

Comment: Try to set the value of Copy to Output Directory to Copy always in your icon Properties page.
And could you provide some related code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: There's no code to show,  The icon is not referenced anywhere in my application source code.  Just a .ico file added to the project and set as the icon in the settings.  "Icon and Manifest" is selected and the manifest is set to "Embed Manifest with default settings".  In the .csproj file it is set as <ApplicationIcon>Loader.ico</ApplicationIcon>. I have set Copy to Output Directory to "Copy Always" but this has no change on the files output when publishing.  I still receive "Unable to apply publish properties for item 'loader.ico'" in the output window when publishing.

Comment: Go to the "Publish" tab and click on "Application Files". Check the "Show all files" checkbox and scroll through the file list. Is there a file with a yellow exclamation mark? If there is, right-click the file and delete the option.

Comment: When "Show all files" is checked, there are no files marked with the yellow bang (exclamation mark)

Comment: According to your description, my test did not encounter any problems. I suggest you update your Visual Studio and create a new project to check if you still encounter the same problem.

Comment: @K_Trenholm did you get any luck with this problem? I'm facing same issue

Comment: @DanielZhang-MSFT you can try to add an extra DLL project. I have the Common netstandard2 project having file of type Content.
This project is referenced by the main WPF App project net7.0. All files which are content of the WPF project are marked as `Excluded (Auto)` in the "Application Files" but included anyway. All files are attached to the referenced Common project are marked as `Included (auto)` and missed in the final output.

I had to move files to the solution root and reference them as links so they would "like" attached by the WPF application itself

Comment: @DanielZhang: also encountering the same problem with lastly updated Visual Studio 2019 16.11.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm from my very own experience ***how frustrating this is***. I have tried anything and everything.
For the time being - until this issue is sorted - I am suggesting that you manually add the .ico file to the Apllication_1_0_0_x folder and appending '.deploy' at the very end.

So file will look like 'my-icon.ico.deploy'.

It works. Tried and tested.

Comment: This managed to do it.  Silly solution, I wouldn't figure you could just append the .deploy in the end and it would work but here we are.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I have the same exact problem, I tried your solution, it did make the app installable, but when I try to open it, it just does not open. I kept an eye on task manager while opening the app, it shows up, gets suspended and closed. any help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem your application .ico file causes this error so you have to change its properties setting to **Build Action: Content** and **Copy To Output Directory: Copy always**.
hope it works

Comment: This was addressed in the original question.  It had no effect in my case.

Comment: Didn't help for me either

Comment: Didn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helped:
Publish -> Show all (Settings current project) -> Settings -> Application Files -> (Show all files):
Find ico file, select publish status to Include | (Required) | Include.

From now on, the ICO file will be added when publishing

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the icon loading problem that I initially "solved" with Avrohom's method, I faced some issue with WebView2 not working / being loaded.

Both of these problems stopped when I disabled the click once publishing profile (`.pubxml`) option for producing a single EXE file:

```
<PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
```

Tested with .NET6, Visual Studio 2022